# Array in While loop like sql fetch_array

Tags: php, sql-server

we are using php+sqlserver with stored procedures in a project. our customer wants to put another server(lets say X server) between our application and database server.
we will send requests to X and it will connect to DB and will return data to application.
right now we are using 2 functions. db_request (it has sqlsrv_request) and db_fetch (it has sqlsvr_fetch_array).
for example, when we select some cities, we are calling select_user_by_city  procedure.

```
$req = db_request("select_user_by_city",array("city_id"=>1));
while($result=db_fetch($req)){blablabla}
```

and my problem begins on this point. i changed inside of db_request function and add some curl and json code in it. its sends the request to X server. X server calling sqlsrv_request and selecting data and returning data as json again. im converting json to array in db_fetch function in application server. but when it proceed to while loop, its going infinite loop. because returning data is not resource anymore, its an array.
is there anyway to make this thing work without change all while's to foreach ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're looping the db_fetch every time the while loop finishes once. It most likely means db_fetch will never return false, but always an array.

Either change db_fetch to return an array when it has no further information anymore (you probably have to save some state, so db_fetch knows when it is done) or yes, change them to foreach loops.

Comment: Here is what i did: There is a extension named `runkit`, for php. With this extension you can rename the functions. So i renamed `next()` function as `db_fetch`. When call `db_fetch`, its actually calling php's `next` function. But it was not enough, because, when you put this function to while loop, as it mentioned in http://php.net/manual/en/function.next.php `next` function always return next value. So i just added a null element to beginning of all arrays, all working great!

Answer (score 0):

ok i did this changing all db_fetchs to next() function in codes. its works great!

```
while($result=next($req)) {blablabla
```